# loss of scale when performing calculation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm performing a calculation and I don't get the answer I expect. I lose some scale doing the calculation.

Calc is: 651/1000 * -413.72063274 = -269.33213191 (to 8 d.p)

In SQL Server I do this:

```
declare @var numeric(28,8)
declare @a numeric(28,8)
declare @b numeric(28,8)

set @var = -413.72063274
set @a   = 651.00000000
set @b   = 1000.00000000

select CAST((@a/@b) * @var as numeric(28,8)) as result_1
     , CAST(CAST(@a as numeric(28,8)) 
      /CAST(@b as numeric(28,8)) as numeric(28,8)) 
      *CAST(@var as numeric (28,8))   as result_2
```

The results is

result_1: -269.33213200 (correct to 6dp)
result_2 : -269.332132   (correct to 6dp)

How do I get the query to return: -269.33213191 (correct to 8dp)?

Comment: The query you posted isn't valid. It has a hanging `/` Can you please fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific case, you could cheat by first multiplying all values and dividing the final result back with this multiplier.

```
declare @var numeric(28,8)
declare @a numeric(28,8)
declare @b numeric(28,8)
declare @m numeric(28,8)

set @var = -413.72063274
set @a   = 651.00000000
set @b   = 1000.00000000
set @m   = 10000000


select CAST(((@a*@m) * (@var*@m) / (@b*@m)) AS NUMERIC(28, 8)) / @m 
-- Result: -269.3321319137
```

**Edit**

on the other hand, following retains its precision without using a multiplier

```
select CAST(@a * @var AS NUMERIC(28, 8)) / @b
-- Result: -269.3321319140
```

Answer (score 6):

The rules for `decimal` to `decimal` conversion for multiplication and division [are described in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx).

> *The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a
>   result precision is greater than 38,
>   the corresponding scale is reduced to
>   prevent the integral part of a result
>   from being truncated.

but leaves it unspecified exactly how such truncation is performed. [This is documented here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx). However sometimes it is easier just to use trial and error!

The following intermediate casts give you the desired result. Can you live with those?

```
DECLARE @var NUMERIC(19,8)
DECLARE @a NUMERIC(19,8)
DECLARE @b NUMERIC(19,8)

SET @var = -413.72063274
SET @a   = 651.00000000
SET @b   = 1000.00000000

DECLARE @v SQL_VARIANT 
SET @v =  CAST(@a/@b AS NUMERIC(24,10))* CAST(@var AS NUMERIC(23,8))

SELECT    CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'BaseType') AS VARCHAR(30)) AS BaseType,    
          CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'Precision') AS INT) AS PRECISION,    
          CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'Scale') AS INT) AS Scale
```

Answer (score 0):

You start with division and after that multiply. The loss of precision is in the division. This is rounded to 8 dp and the result is multiplied by a 3 digit (413) value (hence the missing last two digits)

A solution would be to use larger precision for intermediate results, or do your multiplication first.

(@a * @var) / @b is mathematically equal to your calculation, but might give more accurate results.

Comment: The division actualy gives 10dp. It is the ensuing multiplication that causes the truncation.