# Entity Framework / SQL Server strange decimal division behaviour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in my SQL server 2008 R2 database which includes two nullable decimal(16,6) columns.  Let's call them column1 and column2.

When I try to run a Linq query against the entity generated from this table:

```
Table.Select(r => new Foo
                  {
                     Bar = (r.Column1 + r.Column2) / 2m
                  }
            );
```

I get a **System.OverflowException** if column1 + column2 >= 15846. The message of the exception is only:

> **Conversion overflows.**

With a bit of trial and error I've managed to make the query work with the following:

```
Table.Select(r => new Foo
                  {
                     Bar = (r.Column1 + r.Column2).HasValue ? 
                         (r.Column1 + r.Column2).Value / 2m : 0
                  }
            );
```

However, I was wondering if anyone could explain what was going wrong with the initial query.

---

**Edit**

The first query generates this SQL:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
([Extent1].[Column1] + [Extent1].[Column2]) / cast(2 as decimal(18)) AS [C2]
FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
```

With a value of 10000 for both columns, running the query manually in SSMS the result is `10000.0000000000000000000000000` (25 decimal zeros).

The second query has this SQL:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Column1] + [Extent1].[Column2] IS NOT NULL)
     THEN ([Extent1].[Column1] + [Extent1].[Column2]) / cast(2 as decimal(18))
     ELSE cast(0 as decimal(18))
     END AS [C2]
FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
```

Running the query in SSMS returns `10000.00000000000000000000` (20 decimal zeros). Apparently there is a problem when EF tries to convert the first value (with 25 decimal zeros) into a decimal but with the second (with 20 decimal zeros) it works.

In the meantime it turned out that the problem also occurs with non-nullable columns and even a single decimal(16, 6) column. The following ...

```
Table.Select(r => new Foo
                  {
                     Bar = r.Column1 / 2m
                  }
            );
```

... throws the same conversion exception (with a value of 20000 in the `Column1`).

- Why do those two SQL queries result in two different numbers of digits?
- And why can't the first number be converted into a `decimal` by EF?

Comment: Forgive me that I have heavily added stuff to your question. I wanted to provide an answer but found only new questions. I've put what I found so far under the "Edit" in your question.

Comment: [See the links in my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663351/loss-of-scale-when-performance-calculation/5663463#5663463) for the rules SQL Server uses for scale and precision in decimal division.