# How does SQL Server determine the number of significant digits when rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two database fields that require significant precision - one column is decimal(36,12) and another is decimal(36,24).

When multiplying them I was expecting that precision will be preserved, however that seems not to be the case - I actually get less precision. For example when running following SQL:

```
SELECT 3.035 * 0.333333333333333333333333 AS Normal

SELECT CAST(3.035 AS DECIMAL(36,12)) * CAST(0.333333333333333333333333 AS DECIMAL(36,24)) AS Cast12

SELECT CAST(3.035 AS DECIMAL(36,24)) * CAST(0.333333333333333333333333 AS DECIMAL(36,24)) AS Cast24
```

I get following results:

```
Normal : 1.011666666666666666666665655

Cast12 : 1.011667

Cast24 : 1.0116666666667
```

I guess this is because multiplication is operation that usually yields "bigger" number. I obviously can find a way around this (Cast24 is "good enough"), but I want to understand how exactly does SQL Server determines when to round and what digits to keep?

Comment: Your examples would make more sense if you cast the final result (after the multiplications), rather than casting the two operands *before* multiplying them.

Comment: See the links in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5663463/73226

Comment: Robert... If you do that with "SELECT CAST(CAST(3.035 AS DECIMAL(36,24)) * CAST(0.333333333333333333333333 AS DECIMAL(36,24)) AS DECIMAL(36,24)) AS Cast36", you get 1.011666666666700000000000, which still shows that the multiplication operation is losing precision.

Comment: But you're right, if you ONLY cast "after", then precision is preserved:  "SELECT CAST(3.035 * 0.333333333333333333333333 AS DECIMAL(36,24)) AS Cast36" yields: 1.011666666666666666666666

Answer (score 0):

The combination of the following articles should answer your question.

http://cuisinecode.blogspot.com/2014/04/losing-precision-after-multiplication.html
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx