# Why SQL Server throws Arithmetic overflow error using ROUND?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Why something as simple as

```
SELECT ROUND(0.99535, 2)
```

returns an Arithmetic overflow error in SQL SERVER 2008 R2?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation. It explains this behavior quite clearly.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server

Comment: See Martin's answer here and follow the BOL link for the official docs on decimal operations https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663463/1508467.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final datatype is `DECIMAL(5,5)` so there is no place for `1.0` value.

```
SELECT ROUND(0.99535, 2) 
-- it would round to 1.0000 but it is to big for DECIMAL(5,5)
<=>
SELECT CAST(1 AS numeric(5,5))
-- Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
```

Checking metadata:

```
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set  
(N'SELECT ROUND(0.99535, 2) AS result', null, 0) ;  
-- name     system_type_name
-- RESULT   numeric(5,5)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=708bb5d08e2459dc7b820114b6d177a4)**

---

To avoid this problem you could change the precision to 6.

```
SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(NUMERIC(6,5), 0.99535),2)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=218ec2608e1225682700bc84aec6556a)**

Comment: You should include how to fix it.

Comment: If you want to add it will delete my answer.

Comment: And how can I fix it if I don't know how many digits the number will have (before and after the decimal place)?

Comment: @Fran Of course you know, I guess  that you don't ROUND based on literal but some column/variable which has datatype defined. If you are not sure just use `DECIMAL(38,18)`